# Flutter background location service killed by system(mostly Huawei)

Tags: flutter, geolocation, flutter-background

I develop flutter app with background location listener and on most device is all work, but on some device system kill app when app in background(tray/lock screen/another app on foreground). I need result for android part.

I have tried use:
[flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) with setForeground/setBackground params,
[geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) with notification.
I tried combinate this libs, but it's don't have result.

My permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Services in AndroidManifest:

```
        <service
            android:name="id.flutter.flutter_background_service.BackgroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location" />
```

More problems with Huawei. I tried request permission for ignor battery and other battery optinions but nothng help.
Someone can help me with this? How I can add my app to system **whitelist**, or maybe who knows another solution. Thanks.

Comment: While this might not help, you may want to see this: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service, try to run your code in isolation using this package and save the data in the shared preference or hive, then get the saved data once you end the background service.

Comment: Phil, I have tried this. I need listener for location(coordinate and speed) on real time for calculate some params.

Comment: Dhafin Rayhan, I read this, and user try to ignore battery optimizations, but anyway system kill app. In some cases, the system writes a message: "The application often checks your location. This drains the battery." Although the user has granted permissions to disable optimization.